# Pycharm adds weird argument to the remote interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-debugging

I have a Linux server with `Python 2.7` installed on it and many python files. My goal is to be able to use Pycharm to edit the python files and run them by using Pycharm's remote interpreter feature. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html) and I am unable to run files from Pycharm remotely. While I can edit them remotely, I can't run them from Pycharm's terminal. When I try to run the script using remote interpreter:

> ssh://root@**ip_address**:22/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u <3c6e5936-8354-41cf-ab66-8f1a2a214d85>/core3/dbu3.py

I get this as output:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7: can't open file '<3c6e5936-8354-41cf-ab66-8f1a2a214d85>/core3/dbu3.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Where did `<3c6e5936-8354-41cf-ab66-8f1a2a214d85>` come from? This should be the root path (which I have set to /var/www/html), but it is not. I've also tried to change deployment path and still had the same issue.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Can you add picture of configuration that runs this program ? It's on top right when you click on last executed python script.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There are different configurations. Can you show an example image of a configuration?

Comment: I meant https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html